# Change Start Menu Style and Auto-Hide Option on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Consider a Windows XP machine that I'm on regularly where any changes I make don't stick.

It has the taskbar not on auto-hide and the "old" Windows 98 start menu, which is stupid and nigh-on un-useable.

I'd like to be able to have a program that will automatically run when I insert my jumpdrive that changes those settings so I don't have to fiddle with it every time.

How can this be done?

I don't think the computer has the .NET Framework installed.

Comment: More concerning is why the changes "don't stick". The work-around shouldn't be needed. Attack this problem at the root. Will they stick on the Administrator account? What type of account are you running under: Admin, User, Power User, etc?

Comment: It's not a personal computer, it's a school computer and they've set it up like that.

Comment: Who said it was a "personal computer"? What's the material difference? The point is, the profiles are being locked down to the admin's preferences. This is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: No, I don't think it is. I want to know how to write a program to change the two settings I mentioned. If that isn't a StackOverflow question I don't know what is.

Comment: as campbell stated, if the changes don't stick, it's probably not meant to. However, if you are able to change them during your current session, and the admin hasn't locked that down, then why not have a script that can do it for you automatically? If the admin didn't lock it down during a user session... its his/her fault right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to write a small script with [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to perform the tasks. Auto-hiding the taskbar automatically requires either GUI interaction, or registry changes (which you probably don't have the ability to change registry entries, and if you did, it would probably revert back to the original settings after your user session is terminated). I believe the same rules apply to the look of the start menu as well.

NOTE: Do keep in mind... if this is a place such as a school campus, your user agreement more than likely stated that you are not allowed to run programs unapproved by the administrator(s), and you may be subject to disciplinary action. I've heard of students getting suspensions, and in colleges, having their user ids revoked or even being put on academic probation. It all depends on how strict the I.T. dept is for the facility and how paranoid the upper-staff is about such actions.

Comment: The computers are actually using DeepFreeze, which restores the computers back to a saved config at logout or restart. I can make any registry changes I want, they just don't stick. The school hasn't locked down the computers much because of the DeepFreeze program, there isn't much of anything you can, normally, do to mess up the computers, so they're pretty lenient.
What registry keys would I change, or how would I go about finding them?

Comment: It doesn't matter because in order to take in effect the reg key changes, it would require you to restart your current session, which in turn deep freeze will erase your changes.